# Question on Ruby collect method

Tags: ruby, collect

I have an array of hashes

Eg:

```
cars = [{:company => "Ford", :type => "SUV"},
        {:company => "Honda", :type => "Sedan"},
        {:company => "Toyota", :type => "Sedan"}]

# i want to fetch all the companies of the cars
cars.collect{|c| c[:company]}
# => ["Ford", "Honda", "Toyota"] 

# i'm lazy and i want to do something like this
cars.collect(&:company)
# => undefined method `company'
```

I was wondering if there is a similar shortcut to perform the above.

Comment: I don't think that's lazy. That's concise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your current code `cars.collect{|c| c[:company]}` is the best way if you're enumerating over an arbitrary array. The method you would pass in via the & shortcut would have to be a method defined on Hash since each object in the array is of type `Hash`. Since there is no `company` method defined for `Hash` you get the "undefined method 'company'" error.

You could use `cars.collect(&:company)` if you were operating on an Array of Cars though, because each object passed into the `collect` block would be of type `Car` (which has the company method available). So maybe you could modify your code so that you use an array of Cars instead.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. That's what I initially thought as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could convert the hashes to OpenStructs.

```
require 'ostruct'
cars = [{:company => "Ford", :type => "SUV"},
        {:company => "Honda", :type => "Sedan"},
        {:company => "Toyota", :type => "Sedan"}]
cars = cars.map{|car| OpenStruct.new(car)}

p cars.map( &:company )
#=> ["Ford", "Honda", "Toyota"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to use in your case, because in collect you use method `[]` and argument :company. The construction &:company takes labels `:company` and converts to `Proc`, so it's only one argument - the name of method.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Ruby hashes can't do that. Clojure maps on the other hand have functions for each key which return the corresponding value, which would be easy enough to do if you are so inclined (you should also add the corresponding `respond_to?` method):

```
>> class Hash
..   def method_missing(m)
..     self.has_key?(m) ? self[m] : super
..     end
..   end #=> nil
>> cars.collect(&:company) #=> ["Ford", "Honda", "Toyota"]
>> cars.collect(&:compay)
NoMethodError: undefined method `compay' for {:type=>"SUV", :company=>"Ford"}:Hash
```

Note: I'm not advising this, I'm just saying it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another horrible monkeypatch you shouldn't really use:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    if self.to_s =~ /bracket_(.*)/
      Proc.new {|x| x[$1.to_sym]}
    else
      Proc.new {|x| x.send(self)}
    end
  end
end

cars = [{:company => "Ford", :type => "SUV"},
        {:company => "Honda", :type => "Sedan"},
        {:company => "Toyota", :type => "Sedan"}]

cars.collect(&:bracket_company)
```